# creating dynamic radio button w/ JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a project where I need to give the users several different sets of radio button options based on a given value they select in a drop down menu.

For instance..

```
<select id="aaa">
<option>red</option>
<option>blue</option>
<option>other</option>
</select>

<div id="abc">
Input<BR>
option 1 <input type="radio" name="colorinput" value="1" />
option 2 <input type="radio" name="colorinput" value="2"  />
</div>
<BR>
<div id="def">
Description<BR>
option 1 <input type="radio" name="colordesc" value="1" />
option 2 <input type="radio" name="colordesc" value="2" />
</div>
<BR>
```

I would simply like to add/remove options from either(or both) lists of radio options each time they make a different selection.

Comment: Small point, but for valid XHTML your <BR>s should really be <br />s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // add a new input when a new color is chosen, for example
    $('#aaa').change(function() {
        var radio = $('<input>').attr({
            type: 'radio', name: 'colorinput', value: '3'
        });
        $(':radio:last-child', '#abc').after(radio).after('option 3 ');
    });
});
```

It is [dynamically creating](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#htmlownerDocument) a new input and inserting it [after](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/after#content) the [last radio](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lastChild) inside the `#abc` element.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for.  I can't seem to get it to work though. No errors or anything.. just doesn't add the radio option.

Comment: Did you get my latest revision? I tested it on a page with the HTML you have and it works.

Comment: yes I got it.. but for some reason it doesn't seem to want to work.  Any ideas to what it could be on my end?

Comment: No idea. Nothing happens when you change the select? I'll upload a working version in a second....

Comment: Ooo, I know what. You have to wrap your code around document.ready

Comment: The radiobutton created like this cannot be selected in IE6.
Read this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061526/dynamically-generated-radiobutton-by-jquery-cannot-be-selected-in-ie6

Answer (score 0):

From Paolo Bergantino's post try instead of:

```
$(':radio:last-child', '#abc').after(radio).after('option 3 ');
```

This:

```
$(':radio:last-child', '#abc').after(radio).after('option:eq(2)');
```