# dynamically create radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, grails, radio-button

Referring to [creating dynamic radio button w/ JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702925/creating-dynamic-radio-button-w-jquery) , I was thinking how can this be handled if the input value('red' or 'blue') is retrieved from the database on a page load.

Taking the same example from the above link, if Red, blue or other dynamic values, how can we build radio buttons on the fly  - Red = 1 radio button, blue = 2 radio buttons...etc?
I am new to this. I am using grails at the moment to try this out. Is there a jquery-ish way to do it? I didn;t find any tags in grails to implement this!

**EDIT**: I was pointed out to radioGroup(grails tag), what I intend to have is a CSS based class(that contains a gif), containing different images that need to be shown based on different values. - something similar to showing star-rating from a database(not based on user selection) - red/blue etc.

```
<select id="aaa">
    <option>red</option>
    <option>blue</option>
    <option>other</option>
</select>

<div id="abc">
    Input<br>
    option 1 <input type="radio" name="colorinput" value="1" />
    option 2 <input type="radio" name="colorinput" value="2"  />
</div>
<br>
<div id="def">
    Description<br>
    option 1 <input type="radio" name="colordesc" value="1" />
    option 2 <input type="radio" name="colordesc" value="2" />
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this on page load (i.e. not in response to an AJAX request), then you do not need JQuery, you need the [radioGroup](http://grails.org/doc/1.1/ref/Tags/radioGroup.html) grails tag, with the `values` and `labels` parameters filled by your database query result.

Comment: @micahel borgwardt, I have a CSS based class(that contains a gif), which contains different images that need to be shown based on different values. - something like a star rating, but not exactly.

Comment: So you want to change CSS classes when a different radiobutton is selected? In that case, this question is badly worded, since the creation of the radiobutton does not need to be dynamic and isn't the real issue.

Comment: no, my values are in the database "red, blue, etc", based on the values, I need to show radio buttons (working with jquery plugin star-rating) instead of star, i am showing varying images.
so I need to have something like the jquery star plugin like 
<input name="star3" type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled"/>
would you know how to embed or call CSS class from the radioGroup or grails tag? thanks for your time.

Comment: in that case I think all you have to do is to add a class attribute to the g:radioGroup tag.

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to write your own radiobutton taglib. It's very easy to do that in grails: http://grails.org/Dynamic+Tag+Libraries

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){ //$(document).ready(function(){ // same thing
    var colors=[];
    colors['red']=1;
    colors['blue']=2;
    colors['other']=3;
    $('#aaa').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('#abc, #def').find('input')
            .removeClass('red')
            .removeClass('blue')
            .removeClass('other');
        $('#abc, #def').find('input[value=' + colors[value] + ']).addCLass(value);
        });
    });
```