# Dynamically generated radiobutton by jQuery cannot be selected in IE6

Tags: jquery

I need to dynamically generate radio or checkbox by jQuery.
I use the following code:

```
var type = "radio"; // maybe checkbox
$('<input type="'+ type +'">').attr({
            name: "ename", value: "1"
})
```

However, the radio generated cannot be selected in IE6(other browsers are fine).
What should I do?

marcc's answer solves my problem.

Comment: How are you appending it to the document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the way IE6 works, you cannot set the Name attribute on elements created dynamically.

Set the Name attribute before the attr.

`$('<input type="' + type + '" name="ename">').attr('value', '1');`
or even
`$('<input type="' + type + '" name="ename" value="1">');`

Comment: I just test it and it works.
I read this post before to create the input element:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702925/creating-dynamic-radio-button-w-jquery

I think I'll need to post response to alert people about this.